# Grouped dumbbell chart becomes wonky when I add shapes

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following data showing percent agreement of white vs. black people in various domains. I want to create a grouped dumb-bell chart where the National values and the State values are right next to each other for easy comparison.

```
Domain = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", 
"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", 
"G", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G") 

Area = c("State", "State", 
"State", "State", "State", "State", "State", "National", "National", 
"National", "National", "National", "National", "National", "State", 
"State", "State", "State", "State", "State", "State", "National", 
"National", "National", "National", "National", "National", "National"

race = c("White", "White", "White", "White", "White", "White", 
"White", "White", "White", "White", "White", "White", "White", 
"White", "Black", "Black", "Black", "Black", "Black", "Black", 
"Black", "Black", "Black", "Black", "Black", "Black", "Black", 
"Black") 

pct_agreement = c(0.557610213756561, 0.735042750835419, 
0.567375898361206, 0.633762538433075, 0.64091557264328, 0.750356614589691, 
0.564539015293121, 0.651861846446991, 0.697574973106384, 0.653521358966827, 
0.713940441608429, 0.680985689163208, 0.751584351062775, 0.642535984516144, 
0.488484561443329, 0.581625580787659, 0.456939995288849, 0.580652594566345, 
0.630399644374847, 0.711643815040588, 0.347775995731354, 0.627996683120728, 
0.668737232685089, 0.610245823860168, 0.690373718738556, 0.705771028995514, 
0.738830924034119, 0.550933301448822)
```

[image]

When my code is as following, I get a graph where all the dots line up nicely:

```
df <- data.frame(Domain, Area, race, pct_agreement)

ggplot(df) +
  geom_point(aes(x=Domain, y=pct_agreement, color=Area), 
             position=position_dodge(width=1)) +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

But when I try to make the shapes different depending on whether the respondents are black or white, everything suddenly looks wonky. Is this a bug? Is there any way to fix it or work around it?

I am also not sure how to add a line between the ends of the "dumbbells" -- I tried to use geom_line(aes(group=Area)) but that led to *all* of the dumbbells being connected.

```
ggplot(df) +
  geom_point(aes(x=Domain, y=pct_agreement, color=Area, shape=race), 
             position=position_dodge(width=1)) +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

Note: I've looked through a lot of posts on this site to try to find answers, and many suggest using facets. That doesn't work for me because my boss wants it all on one graph.

Comment: Can you `dput(df)` please? You'll want to use geom_segment for the bars.

Comment: You can use `geom_path` as well for the lines, you just need to be specific about the groups paths should be drawn between

Comment: For geom_segment, what do I put down for X and Xend? I have geom_segment(aes(x=?, y=Domain, xend=?, yend=Domain))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dodging happens based on groups, and with two categorical variables (`race` and `Area`) you end up with groups of four for each domain, and thus the points are dodged into four different positions. You can avoid this by explicitly setting the group aesthetic.

First the data:

```r
Domain = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", 
           "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", 
           "G", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G") 

Area = c("State", "State", 
         "State", "State", "State", "State", "State", "National", "National", 
         "National", "National", "National", "National", "National", "State", 
         "State", "State", "State", "State", "State", "State", "National", 
         "National", "National", "National", "National", "National", "National")

race = c("White", "White", "White", "White", "White", "White", 
         "White", "White", "White", "White", "White", "White", "White", 
         "White", "Black", "Black", "Black", "Black", "Black", "Black", 
         "Black", "Black", "Black", "Black", "Black", "Black", "Black", 
         "Black") 

pct_agreement = c(0.557610213756561, 0.735042750835419, 
                  0.567375898361206, 0.633762538433075, 0.64091557264328, 0.750356614589691, 
                  0.564539015293121, 0.651861846446991, 0.697574973106384, 0.653521358966827, 
                  0.713940441608429, 0.680985689163208, 0.751584351062775, 0.642535984516144, 
                  0.488484561443329, 0.581625580787659, 0.456939995288849, 0.580652594566345, 
                  0.630399644374847, 0.711643815040588, 0.347775995731354, 0.627996683120728, 
                  0.668737232685089, 0.610245823860168, 0.690373718738556, 0.705771028995514, 
                  0.738830924034119, 0.550933301448822)

df <- data.frame(Domain, Area, race, pct_agreement)
```

Now the plot:

```r
library(tidyverse)

ggplot(df) +
  geom_point(
    aes(
      x=Domain, y=pct_agreement, color=Area, shape=race,
      group = Area
    ), 
    position=position_dodge(width=1)
  ) +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-11-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Connecting the dots with lines is difficult. I think it deserves a separate question. I posted one [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58761704/4975218)